Movie with a canyon scene shot in Tozeur, Tunisia in 1998
I was at this place in Tozeur (Tunisia) in Summer 1998. I happened the see a movie scene being shot in rocks just outside of the town, at a place called Le Belvedère:

Actual view (source)

Aerial view of the location with Google Maps
My memories have faded in the meantime, I remember few details.
The scene shot was about a woman in traditional clothes (Spanish or Arabian) riding a galloping horse coming at this place and perhaps meeting someone on the rocky side, maybe a local warrior. At some distance there was a small isolated military outpost, made of clay, same color than the desert around. And maybe it was flanked by a flag (could be an Italian or French flag).
The story could be set in 1930, but I'm really not sure.
Several movies have scenes shot in the area of Tozeur, which is at the border of the desert, like The English Patient, Fort Saganne and Star Wars, but this was further away from the town, e.g. near Sidi Bouhlel canyon.
I think the film unit was Italian. I'm curious about this movie (which could be a TV movie never shown in theaters). Does anybody have a suggestion for the title?
